# How can I exclude objects from being mapped by Apache Commons Betwixt?

Tags: java, apache-commons, betwixt

ORMapper that I use extends some of its own attributse all objects that mapped, now I need to generate XML from objects, but I don't want to generate information about my ORMapper related objects, so how can I exclude ORMapper related classes from being generated to XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here, go to section [Ignoring Properties](http://commons.apache.org/betwixt/guide/binding.html).

By the way, is there any particular reason you are using Betwixt? May be the app is already using that, thats fair enough. But I am just afraid if you are starting to use it in some application. Because thats pretty much frozen already. Try looking at alternatives [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), or [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

[See here, the "Ignoring properties" section](http://commons.apache.org/betwixt/guide/binding.html)